# Preserving two random numbers through game loop

Tags: php, random

My code should provide two random numbers and have the user enter their product (multiplication).

If you enter a wrong answer, it tells you to guess again, but keeps the same random numbers until you answer correctly. Answer correctly, and it starts over with a new pair of numbers.

The below code changes the value of the two random numbers even if I entered the wrong number. I would like to keep the values the same until the correct answer is entered.

```
<?php
$num1=rand(1, 9);
$num2=rand(1, 9);
$num3=$num1*$num2;
$num_to_guess = $num3;
echo $num1."x".$num2."= <br>";


if ($_POST['guess'] == $num_to_guess) 
        { // matches!
            $message = "Well done!";
        } 
        elseif ($_POST['guess'] > $num_to_guess) 
        {
            $message = $_POST['guess']." is too big! Try a smaller number.";
        } 
            elseif ($_POST['guess'] < $num_to_guess) 
            {
                $message = $_POST['guess']." is too small! Try a larger number.";
            } 
                else  
                { // some other condition
                    $message = "I am terribly confused.";
                }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h2><?php echo $message; ?></h2>
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="answer" value="<?php echo $answer;?>">
<input type="hidden" name="expression" value="<?php echo $expression;?>">
What is the value of the following multiplication expression: <br><br>
<?php echo $expression; ?> <input type="text" name="guess"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Check">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: and question is ?  ..what do you mean with don't work properly .. error? ..

Comment: the code i provided changes the value of the two rand numbers even if i entered the wrong number. i would like to keep the values the same until the correct answer is entered.

Comment: Activate error reporting (`error_reporting( E_ALL ); ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );` at top of your script): you will see a lot of warning in your script. Also you compare answer with a new multiplication and you never define `$answer` and `$expression`

Comment: Is this a school assignment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to keep the same numbers, you have to store them on the page and then check them when the form is submitted using php. You must also set the random number if the form was never submitted. In your case, you were always changing num1 and num2.  I tried to leave as much of your original code intact, but it still needs some work to simplify it.

1. First I added 2 more hidden field in the html called num1 and num2
2. Second, I set $num1 and $num2 to the value that was submitted from the form.
3. After following the rest of the logic, I make sure that $num1 and $num2 are reset if the answer is correct of it the form was never submitted.

You can see the comments in the code below.

Additionally, if you were going to use this in a production environment, you would want to validate the values being passed in from the form so that malicious users don't take advantage of your code. :)

```
 <?php
// Setting $num1 and $num2 to what was posted previously and performing the math on it.
$num1 = $_POST['num1'];
$num2 = $_POST['num2'];
$num_to_guess = $num1*$num2;

// Check for the correct answer
if ($_POST && $_POST['guess'] == $num_to_guess)
{
    // matches!
    $message = "Well done!";
    $num1=rand(1, 9);
    $num2=rand(1, 9);
} 
// Give the user a hint that the number is too big
elseif ($_POST['guess'] > $num_to_guess)
{
    $message = $_POST['guess']." is too big! Try a smaller number.";
} 
// Give the user a hint that the number is too small
elseif ($_POST['guess'] < $num_to_guess) 
{
    $message = $_POST['guess']." is too small! Try a larger number.";
} 
// If the form wasn't submitted i.e. no POST or something else went wrong
else  
{
    // Only display this message if the form was submitted, but there were no expected values
    if ($_POST)
    {
        // some other condition and only if something was posted
        $message = "I am terribly confused.";
    }
    // set num1 and num2 if there wasn't anything posted
    $num1=rand(1, 9);
    $num2=rand(1, 9);
}

// Show the problem
echo $num1."x".$num2."= <br>";

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h2><?php echo $message; ?></h2>
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="num1" value="<?= $num1 ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="num2" value="<?= $num2 ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="answer" value="<?php echo $num3;?>">
<input type="hidden" name="expression" value="<?php echo $expression;?>">
What is the value of the following multiplication expression: <br><br>
<input type="text" name="guess"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Check">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you load the page for the first time, you have (i.e.) “2*3” as question. `$_POST` is not defined, so `if ($_POST['guess']...` will produce a *undefined index* warning. Then you echo `$message`, but where you define `$message`? `$_POST['guess']` is undefined, so is evaluated as 0, `$num_to_guess` is 6 (=2*3), so `$message` is set to " is too small! Try a larger number.", even if the user has not input anything. The hidden `answer` is set to `$answer`, but this variable is not defined so it is set to nothing (or to “Notice:  Undefined variable: answer”, if you activate error reporting). Same issue for `expression` input and for `echo $expression`.

Try something like this:

```
$newQuestion = True;    // This variable to check if a new multiplication is required
$message     = '';

/* $_POST['guess'] check only if form is submitted: */
if( isset( $_POST['guess'] ) )
{
    /* Comparison with answer, not with new result: */
    if( $_POST['guess'] == $_POST['answer'] )
    {
        $message = "Well done!";
    }
    else
    {
        /* If result if wrong, no new question needed, so we propose same question: */
        $newQuestion = False;
        $answer      = $_POST['answer'];
        $expression  = $_POST['expression'];
        if( $_POST['guess'] > $_POST['answer'] )
        {
            $message = "{$_POST['guess']} is too big! Try a smaller number.";
        }
        else
        {
            $message = "{$_POST['guess']} is too small! Try a larger number.";
        }
    }
}

/* New question is generated only on first page load or if previous answer is ok: */
if( $newQuestion )
{
    $num1       = rand( 1, 9 );
    $num2       = rand( 1, 9 );
    $answer     = $num1*$num2;
    $expression = "$num1 x $num2";
    if( $message ) $message .= "<br>Try a new one:";
    else           $message  = "Try:";
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
(... Your HTML Here ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

This might also be fun to learn. This is a session. Lets you store something temporarily. It is a little dirty. But fun to learn from.
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

```
 <?php
    session_start(); // Starts the Session.

    function Save() { // Function to save $num1 and $num2 in a Session.
        $_SESSION['num1'] = rand(1, 9);
        $_SESSION['num2'] = rand(1, 9);
        $_SESSION['num_to_guess'] = $_SESSION['num1']*$_SESSION['num2'];;
        $Som = 'Guess the number: ' . $_SESSION['num1'] .'*' .$_SESSION['num2'];
    }
     // If there is no session set
     if (!isset($_SESSION['num_to_guess'])) {
         Save();
         $message = "";
     }

     if (isset($_POST['guess'])) {
         // Check for the correct answer
         if ($_POST['guess'] == $_SESSION['num_to_guess']) {
             $message = "Well done!";
             session_destroy(); // Destroys the Session.
             Save(); // Set new Sessions.
         }
         // Give the user a hint that the number is too big
         elseif ($_POST['guess'] > $_SESSION['num_to_guess']) {
             $message = $_POST['guess']." is too big! Try a smaller number.";
             $Som = 'Guess the number: ' . $_SESSION['num1'] .'*' .$_SESSION['num2'];
         }
         // Give the user a hint that the number is too small
         elseif ($_POST['guess'] < $_SESSION['num_to_guess']) {
             $message = $_POST['guess']." is too small! Try a larger number.";
             $Som = 'Guess the number: ' . $_SESSION['num1'] .'*' .$_SESSION['num2'];
         }
         // some other condition
         else { 
             $message = "I am terribly confused.";
         }
    }
    ?>

    <html>
    <body>
    <h2><?php echo $Som . '<br>'; ?>
        <?php echo $message; ?></h2>
        <form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
            <input type="text" name="guess"><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Check">
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```